# the predict function in the code causes value error help resolve

Tags: python, tensorflow, valueerror

it shows value error , I'm not able to figure out why

inside predict_class

```
    res=model.predict(np.array([bow]))[0]
```

inside while loop to input user statement and predict suitable statements from the model

```
    message=input("You : ")
    msg=predict_class(message)
```

Comment: I dont think there is enough information for anyone to give you recommendation. Can you share more of your code with the functions you are calling.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you should add details to your question. It is impossible to answer now. Whenever you have an issue and want some help, you should look at look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, in order to formulate a "quality question". You need to investigate by your own before posting

Comment: Ok i will try to post the complete code in my question